# How to pass the 'syncSend' property in logj2 kafka appender json configuration?

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, log4j, log4j2

I added the Kafka appender to my log4j.json config and wanted to push logs to kafka asynchronously. Upon research I found that this can be done using the 'syncSend' property of log4j kafka appender. However, whenever I try to add the property to my config file, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Kafka contains an invalid element or attribute "syncSend"
```

Here is how my kafka appender property looks like. It works perfectly fine and is shipping logs to kafka but
I am afraid that is happening synchronously:

```
"Kafka": {
            "name": "Kafka",
            "type": "Kafka",
            "topic": "api.logs",
            "syncSend": "false",
            "PatternLayout": {
                "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %C.%M:%L - %X{dd.trace_id} %X{dd.span_id} %m%n"
            },
            "property": [
                {
                    "name": "bootstrap.servers",
                    "value": "bootstrapserver1, bootstrapserver2 ... "
                },
                {
                    "name": "linger.ms",
                    "value": "5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "batch.size",
                    "value": "16384"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Which version of Log4j 2.x are you using? The feature appeared in 2.8. Using a version older than 2.17.1 these days would be unwise.

Comment: One solution is that you can use the `batchSize` property to control the number of log events to be sent in a batch, and the `lingerMs` property to define how long the appender should wait for more log events before sending a batch. By tuning these properties, you can achieve some level of async logging with the Kafka appender.